# Connection state is closed when sending authorization request using DDP protocol

Tags: android, meteor, ddp, java-websocket

I am using kenyee's [Android DDP Client library](https://github.com/kenyee/android-ddp-client) to connect my Android application to a server running Meteor-JS.

I've modified his [Meteor.js Parties ANdroid Demo](https://github.com/kenyee/MeteorPartiesDDPClient). I attempt to login with existing user credentials and get Login Error. Please, help!

I create `DDPStateSingleton` with the following settings:

```
String meteorServer = "http://<sandbox_name>.nitrousbox.com";
Integer meteorPort = 3000;
mInstance = new MyDDPState(context, meteorServer, meteorPort);
```

(Meteor-js server is running in nitrous.io sandbox) And then I perform a user login attempt:

```
MyDDPState.getInstance().login(mEmail, mPassword);
```

But I get `WebsocketNotConnectedException` (it is throwed from `org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl#send(String)`) so my login request ends with error message

```
"Unknown websocket error (exception in callback?)"
```

Singleton state during exception:

```
mConnState = Closed
mMeteorServerAddress = ws://http://<sandbox_name>.nitrousbox.com:3000/websocket
```

It is strange, I see that connection is closed although `connectIfNeeded()` was called before.

**UPD**:
The first received async message from DDP server is of type `error`.
The second received async message is of type `closed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException`.
Hostname should be specified without a protocol:

```
String meteorServer = "<sandbox_name>.nitrousbox.com";
```